# Styling table cell different colors depending on the cell value using erb - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently doing the board for a battleship game on ruby on rails. 
I am stuck on how to change the color of the table cell (depending which of the values in the array @actions is inside. I tryed using case statement and if'statement in the html.erb  but I cant work out the right syntax. And another thing I am wondering: should I do a helper method for this and use it in the html, instead of coding in there?

Here is the controller:

```
class BoardsController < ApplicationController
  def new
      @actions = ['none', 'hit', 'miss', 'ship', 'special']
      @grid = []
      for row in 0..9
          @grid.push([])
          for column in 0..9
            @grid[row].push({
                'action' => @actions.sample
            })
          end
      end
  end
end
```

Here is the view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <% for row in 0..9 %>
        <tr>
            <% for column in 0..9 %>
                <td>
                    <%= @grid[row][column]['action'] %>
                </td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Please edit your question an post the relevant code (i.e. view and controller).

Comment: Welcome to SO :) You need to post your current code here. Not all of it, just the crucial part. Also, a quick spell check won't hurt.

Comment: IMO it's probably easiest to assign the relevant cells a class and use javascript to do the styling.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry for the mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution will be to create CSS classes for each action, something for example:

```
<style>
  .none    { background-color: blue; }
  .hit     { background-color: red; }
  .miss    { background-color: yellow; }
  .ship    { background-color: white; }
  .special { background-color: green; }
</style>
```

And then just add the action (i.e. `@grid[row][column]['action']`) in the `class` attribute for `td` tag:

```
<% for column in 0..9 %>
  <td class="<%= @grid[row][column]['action'] %>"></td>
<% end %>
```

---

Not related to your question, but worth noting: You should also opt to use `each` instead of `for`, is more idiomatic.

For example, your view code could be refactored to:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <% (0..9).each do |row| %>
    <tr>
      <% (0..9).each do |column| %>
        <td class="<%= @grid[row][column]['action'] %>"></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: I am writing down as I read, thanks for the great answer! Every new piece of info is important in the early stages!

Regards, B

Comment: @BobbyBonchev Glad to help! If it works, please don't forget to accept the answer (by clicking the tick). :) Happy coding!

Comment: thanks once again for the tip! Happy coding to you too!